# Declare static class or struct method using expression body in C#

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates, expression, func

I use immutable `readonly` fields along with `public` `Expression<Func<>>` getters all the time as below.

```
public class Person
{
    public static Person Named(string surname, string given) { return new Person(surname, given); } // ugly!

    protected Person(string surname, string given) { _surname = surname; _given = given; }

    private readonly string _surname;
    private readonly string _given;

    public string Name => _given + _surname; // cool!
}
```

I would really like to be able to do that with static methods as above.

I tried different syntax but none worked, ie:

```
public static Person Named => x,y => new Person(x,y);
public static Person Named = (x,y) => new Person(x,y);
public static Person Named => ((x,y) => new Person(x,y));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way is as follows

```
public static Person Named(string surname, string given) => new Person(surname, given);
```

It's worth mentioning that there is no difference in the syntax for instance and static properties/methods.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Out of curiosity, what is the right way to describe this kind of assignment?

Comment: It's just a syntax sugar. The declaration of the function/property remains the same, just the body is shortened.

Comment: @tacos_tacos_tacos It's called an `expression-bodied function`.